# Python mock class with function and property

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am having some trouble patching a class with a function and a property.

The project structure I am working with is as follows:

```
project
|- src
|  |- logic
|  |  |- sub_logic
|  |  |  | __init__.py
|  |  |  | cache.py
|  |  |  | manager.py
|  |  | __init__.py  
|- test
|  | test.py
```

My cache file looks like this

```
class Cache(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    @property
    def Val(self):
        return self._val

    def other_function(self):
        return False
```

The manager file looks like this

```
from cache import Cache


class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = Cache(20)

    def do_something(self):
        if self._cache.Val != 20:
            raise ValueError(u"Val is not 20")

        return True

    def do_something_else(self):
        if self._cache.other_function():
            raise ValueError(u"Something is True")
```

The tests I tried to make are the following:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import PropertyMock, patch

from logic.sub_logic.manager import Manager
from logic.sub_logic.cache import Cache


class ManagerTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_01_cache(self):
        manager = Manager()
        self.assertEqual(manager.do_something(), True)

    @patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache.Val', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    def test_02_cache(self, property_mock):
        property_mock.return_value = 20
        manager = Manager()
        self.assertEqual(manager.do_something(), True)

    @patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache', spec=Cache)
    def test_03_cache(self, cache_mock):
        cache_mock.other_function.return_value = True
        manager = Manager()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            manager.do_something_else()

    @patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache', spec=Cache)
    def test_04_cache(self, cache_mock):
        cache_mock.other_function.return_value = True
        cache_mock.Val = PropertyMock()
        cache_mock.Val.return_value = 20

        manager = Manager()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            manager.do_something_else()
        self.assertEqual(manager.do_something(), True)

    @patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache.Val', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    @patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache', spec=Cache)
    def test_05_cache(self, cache_mock, property_mock):
        cache_mock.other_function.return_value = True
        property_mock.return_value = 20
        manager = Manager()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            manager.do_something_else()
        self.assertEqual(manager.do_something(), True)

    @patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache', spec=Cache)
    def test_06_cache(self, cache_mock):
        cache_mock.other_function.return_value = True
        cache_mock.Val = 20

        manager = Manager()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            manager.do_something_else()
        self.assertEqual(manager.do_something(), True)
```

The problem is that test_04_cache and test_05_cache are not working. 
When debugging the the tests, the mock parameter provided is as I expected it to be. But the Manager creates a MagicMock where the property Val is not a PropertyMock but also a MagicMock.

I inspected test_06_cache in PyCharm Debugger which reports the following:

- `cache_mock.Val = {int}20`
- `manager._cache.Val = {MagicMock}<MagicMock name='Cache().Val' id='61044848'>`

Am I missing something? Or is it not possible?

Comment: If you're mocking out the cache, why do you care if it's really implemented as a property? Just set `cache_mock.Val = 20`.

Comment: You suggest replacing `cache_mock.Val = PropertyMock()
        cache_mock.Val.return_value = 20` with just `cache_mock.Val = 20`? I just tried that and it seems not to work.

Comment: In test_05 you first mock Cache.Val, but then after that you mock Cache which replaces the whole object with MagicMock. This is why in test_05 you see Val as a MagicMock.

Comment: Could you expand on *"seems not to work"*? My point is that the fact that in the real `Cache` the `Val` is a property is irrelevant as far as the `Manager` is concerned, so when you're unit-testing the latter you can just use a regular attribute.

Comment: I extended my question where I created your suggestion. The unittest still fails and the PyCharm Debugger tells me a difference between cache_mock and the instance in manager.

Comment: You need to set `cache_mock().Val` - note that you have access to the class, not the instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the issue.

Comment: THANKYOU! In python2, mock was soooooo simple with mock.StubOutWithMock(Model, 'func'). With python3 it was very different, and the documentation has been hard to find. Your example above gave the understanding I have needed for 4 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use

```
@patch('logic.sub_logic.manager.Cache', spec=Cache)
```

the resulting mock is for the *class*. Your `Manager` then creates an instance by *calling* that class, in `__init__`. You should therefore be setting attributes and return values on `mock_cache()` (note parentheses), which is the "instance" that will be assigned to `manager._cache`, rather than on the "class" `mock_cache`.

Note that, as the manager doesn't know that the cache is using a `@property`, you can just set:

```
mock_cache().Val = 20
```